# python subprocess - How to check if there is not any new data in the PIPE?

Tags: python, subprocess, popen, readline, eof

I have the following example:

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen("cmd",stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE )
p.stdin.write(b'cd\\' + b'\r\n')
p.stdin.write(b'dir' + b'\r\n')
p.stdin.write(b'\r\n')



while True:
    line = p.stdout.readline()
    print(line.decode('ascii'), end='')
    if line.rstrip().decode('ascii') == 'C:\>': #I need to check at this point if there is new data in the PIPE
        print('End of File')
        break
```

I am listening to the PIPE for any output from the subprocess and if there is not any new data coming through the PIPE I would like to stop reading. I would like to have a control statement that would tell me that PIPE is empty. This would help me to avoid problems in case my process freezes or ends with an unexpected result.

Comment: Could you please provide some context for what you're trying to accomplish?  It seems to me there is probably a better way to go about doing what you're doing if we know what you're trying to do.

Comment: The purpose here is to start the shell of a target device. Using subprocess, I am trying to send commands to the shell and capture the response. For example I start the target shell, load the files to the target, run the file, and observe the output. If the output is what I expected, load the next file and run that file. But in some cases when I run the program it may freeze or return an unexpected value. in this case I want to be able to prevent freezing. Escape from the situation and deinitialize everything.

Answer (score 2):

Unless the process is over or there is a signal you are expecting to stop reading at, there is no good way to know ahead of time if there is data in the pipe, because the command will only terminate when it reaches the number of bytes you want to read [.read(n)], reaches a newline char [.readline()], or reaches the end of the file (which doesn't exist until the process is over).

However, you don't need to run cmd.exe to run your program, since your program will already be run in the cmd shell.

I suggest you use subprocess to call the program directly, and handle exceptions/return_code in your code.  You could do something like...

```
import subprocess
import time

p = subprocess.Popen("your_program.exe",
                     "-f", "filename",
                     stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

# If you have to use stdin, do it here.
p.stdin.write('lawl here are my inputs\n')

run_for = 0
while p.poll() == None:
    time.sleep(1)
    if run_for > 10:
        p.kill()
        break
    run_for += 1

if p.return_code == 0:
    ...handle success...
else:
    ...handle failure...
```

You could do this in a loop and spin up a new process that would run the next file.

If it's *that* costly to spin up the program (and if it's not then stop reading now because it's about to get embarrassing) then perhaps (and this is a total hack, but) after your process has run a while, you could pass a particularly odd but innocuous string to p.stdin, as in `p.stdin.write("\n~%$%~\n")`.

If you could get away with that, then you could do something like...

```
for line in p.stdout.readlines():
    if '~%$%~' in line:
        break
```

But holy crap, please don't do that.  It's such a hack.